# import enviroment variables in js file in assets folder in Angular project

Tags: angular, import, environment-variables, esmodules

I created a mobile-device.js file into assets/mobile folder in my Angular project, then I added the file path in the scripts array in angular.json file like this:

```
   "scripts": [
      "src/assets/mobile/mobile-device.js"
    ]
```

Now I need to import in this file (mobile-device.js) my environment variables adding this import statement on the top of the file:

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
```

but when I try to start my project I read in the browser console this error:

> Cannot use import statement outside a module (at scripts.js:1:1)

I think the issue is something related to this -> [How to use a js file by module type in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75330920/how-to-use-a-js-file-by-module-type-in-angular) any idea?

Comment: There is [a feature-request under consideration to allow adding `type="module"` to script references](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/24592), but it hasn't gone anywhere is several months...